# JS- Merge multi demensional array object to array object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have data as below:

```
  [ { propertyId: '3257', amenityId: '98' } ],
  [ { propertyId: '3258', amenityId: '98' } ],
  [ { propertyId: '3259', amenityId: '98' } ],
  [ { propertyId: '3260', amenityId: '98' } ],
  [ { propertyId: '3261', amenityId: '98' } ],
  [ { propertyId: '3262', amenityId: '98' } ],
  [ { propertyId: '3263', amenityId: '98' } ],
  [ { propertyId: '3264', amenityId: '98' } ],
  [ { propertyId: '3265', amenityId: '98' } ],
  [ { propertyId: '3266', amenityId: '98' } ]

expect: 


[
    { propertyId: '3257', amenityId: '98' },
    { propertyId: '3258', amenityId: '98' }
    …......................
]
```

Thank beforehand.

Comment: Simple map would do the trick `const result = data.map(([item]) => item);`

Comment: `data.flatMap(arr => arr[0])`

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting a newer version of JS that supports this, you could simply use:

```
const flattenedArray = myMultiDimArray.flat()
```

Otherwise, you could achieve this with a simple reducer:

```
const flattenedArray = myMultiDimArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc.push(...curr)
    return acc;
}, [])
```